# How to refund payment using paypal android sdk V2?

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am developing an android application with Paypal integration using Paypal's android sdk V2. I have done payment transactions successfully. But i don't know how to cancel the transaction and refund the payment using Paypal sdk V2 (Rest API). Can anyone help me to make it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot refund a transaction from the Android SDK.  You'll have to take the payment id, and call [refund](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#refunds) from your server.

Comment: Thank you for your good answer. Can you give me sample php code to refund the payment using curl ? I am not good in php.

Comment: You can find sample code in many languages on the developer site, [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#refund-a-sale).  You can also try using the [PayPal Php SDK](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php).

Comment: To make refund have i do any changes in the merchant account? That means is any special permission needed to refund?

Comment: I had done a sample refund using the id "PAY-7TW19039DN966743UKO333RA". But i was unable to make the refund. It shows the error response like,                                      {
    "name": "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
    "message": "The requested resource ID was not found",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
    "debug_id": "b34b00ad00d57"
}

Comment: Refund from Android App is possible. I have done that in a project. Please check my answer with working code.

Refund from Android App is possible. I have done that in a project. Please check my answer with working code.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144075/android-paypal-refund-through-app